# "Declined" Vs "Declining"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, grammaticality, adjectives, adjective-phrases

She glossed over the company's declining profits.
 ( original text)

Can I use the word "declined" instead of "declining" so that the sentence becomes as follows :

She glossed over the company's declined profits.

Answer (score 1):

While declined as a replacement would be technically correct, it would sound very awkward, and I would not ever use it (as a straight replacement).  Declined could be used to suggest a specific time period, as in: "She glossed over the company's profits, which had {declined in the last year/quarter, declined since their peak two years ago, declined since the last quarter, declined in/over the summer of 2018 but had since recovered}" - any of those options would be great.

Declining suggests that the loss in profits is ongoing (whether recent or a long-term trend) and that there is worry the decline will continue.  "She glossed over the company's declining profits {(nothing), concerned that she would not be able to pay her creditor's next month, wondering how close she was to having to declare bancruptcy, worried that her life's work would be ruined}" - any of those options (including nothing added) would work.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct with difference in meaning :

1. Company's 'declining profits' means profits which are still declining or diminishing. Here the present participle 'declining' shows that the downward fall of the company's profit is still going on.
2. Company's 'declined profits' means the downward fall of the company's profit has now stopped. Past participle shows a completed action.